# Find an efficient algorithm for a matrix operation

Tags: algorithm

This is an interview question:

> For a matrix, we define an operation that when we add 1 to one entry,
>   all the surrounding entries (up, down, left, right) will also added by
>   1. Given a positive matrix, find an algorithm to determine if the matrix can be constructed from zero matrix using such operation.

What is an efficient algorithm to solve the question?

What I can currently think of is to use backtracking to try every possible combinations, however this is definitely not efficient. The question is sort of like Lights Off game, but it is not 0/1 here which makes more complicated.

Thanks.

Edit:

For example:

```
3 3 can be constructed from 0 0 -> 1 1 -> 2 2 -> 3 3
1 2                         0 0    1 0    1 1    1 2
```

Comment: What happens, if I hit first or last col/row: Wrapping or cutting?

Comment: Your example is impossible: 1/1/1/1 can't be created from a zero matrix ...

Comment: @EugenRieck Edited, now here is a possible one. Try to solve it reversely.

Comment: Seems like a simple dynamic programming challenge.

Answer (score 1):

Linear algebra?

```
Cell i,j is touched x<sub>ij</sub> times.
```

n<sup>2</sup> variables and equations. Solve. `O(n^6)` by Gaussian method, other faster methods might exists.

Also, matrix is special so might be able to make it faster.

Comment: An approach that uses more of the structure of the problem would be to use a 2-d FFT and the convolution theorem - what you have is a convolution of an unknown matrix and a pattern with 9 1s in a square. Could have problem with getting non-integer answers but if push comes to shove you can use it with branch and bound.

Answer (score 0):

i found few things(for 2x2 matrix), would like to share them first
-sum of all the elements in the matrix should be divisible by 3(then only it is possible).
-we have to express a given matrix in form allowed operation steps

```
3 3  -> 2* 1 1    +    1* 1 1
1 2        0 1            1 0
```

there would be some cases in which this can't be done e.g.

```
5 3  ->2* 1 0  +   2* 1 1     = 4 2
2 4       1 1         0 1       2 4

5 3   -   4 2     = 1 1 (this is not allowed operation)
2 4       2 4       0 0
```

Comment: Wrong: the 3x3 matrix `0 1 0 / 1 1 1 / 0 1 0` is reachable (do the operation just once, to the center element), but the sum of all elements is not divisible by 3.

Comment: Also, the 2x2 matrice `2 4 / 4 2` is reachable (touch two opposite corners twice), but there are no adjacent elements with difference ≤ 1.

Comment: @jrouquie: "thanks for minus",i should have mentioned 2x2 cases specifically.Can you provide a test case in 2x2 where the sum isn't divisible by 3 and still matrix is reduce able ."adjacent elements with difference ≤ 1" was wrong.